# heteroskedasticity of surrogate residuals for ordinal logisitic regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, heteroscedasticity, ordinal-data, diagnostic

I am fitting a ordinal logistic regression. The real model is multivariate, but I am using  a bivariate version for simplicity in this question.

Most references I have seen do not list homoskedasticity as a model assumption for ordinal regression.  However, according to the paper [Residuals and Diagnostics for Ordinal Regression Models: A Surrogate Approach](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6133273/), heteroskedastic (surrogate) residuals suggest model misspecification.

My model is clearly heteroskedastic:

[image: residual plot]

What I would like to know is:

- Does this heteroskedasticity suggest model misspecification?
- What does this heteroskedasticity say about my data and what transformation if any might resolve it?

Comment: Instead of the residuals only could you provide the raw data (numerical, not graph).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide the raw data due to policy, but am happy to put together any other useful visualizations or statistics.

Comment: Impossible to check without data. Bye!

Comment: Even just clarity as to whether homoskedasticity is a model assumption for ordinal regression would be helpful...